# When making a multiplayer game, am I dependent on the browser to not give variables to the player (so he could hack)?

Tags: javascript, browser, node.js, console, socket.io

For example, I have an instance player. I know I can't type: *"player.health = 99999"* to the JavaScript, the browser just doesn't let me, but what if someone made a browser that did let you do that? Or is it impossible to change variables like that by default?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All things that are executed by the client are NOT secure. If you want that is secure, then you have to check it on the server.

Comment: Always assume that the client software can be compromised. That also means to never send any information to the client that the player is not supposed to see, like other players locations and so (unless they should be visible of course :))

Comment: I have to send their locations, how else would the player see where the rest of them are? Also, their locations would just get over-written the next time the server sends them so I wouldn't worry about that. But all the information that the server already **had** should be safe as well. I'm worried about someone changing my code or something...

Comment: 'All security is compromise'—Bruce Schneier. Here the cost of security is more work for the server. You might even tolerate `player.health=9999` in a _game_, but to a *bank* `account.balance=9999` is ruin.

Comment: As I understand, for a **real-time** multiplayer game then the server must authoritatively manage the game state, otherwise the states on the clients risk diverging.

Answer (score 1):

I believe JS debuggers such as Firebug will allow you to change the values of Javascript variables